# Updating one table from another and grab rows which don't match

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a guitar shop, and a website to go with it.

Amongst many other continuing issues are supplier's price changes, so I am trying to sync products to suppliers price lists by uploading each price list to a pre-formated table in my database and then updating rows accordingly by sku.

So, take Gibson guitars, I have a table `products` and a table `PriceList_gibson` which look like this (simplified):

```
**Products:**
id    |    sku    |    description    |    cost     .... more fields


**PriceList_gibson**
id    |    sku    |    description    |    trade    .... more fields
```

I have a web method which looks like this:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function syncPrices(supplierId, tableName)

    Try
        Common.changeData("UPDATE " & tableName & " p, products pp SET pp.rrp= p.rrp, pp.cost= p.trade,  pp.upc= CASE WHEN p.upc <> '' THEN  p.upc ELSE  pp.upc END WHERE pp.sku= p.sku AND pp.supplier ='" & supplierId & "'")
        Return "success|Prices Synced"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "error|" & ex.ToString
    End Try

End Function
```

The crucial part being the SQL statement, which broken down, looks like this:

```
UPDATE " & tableName & " p, products pp 
     SET 
         pp.rrp= p.rrp,  
         pp.cost= p.trade, 
         pp.upc= CASE WHEN p.upc <> '' THEN  p.upc ELSE  pp.upc END 
     WHERE pp.sku= p.sku AND pp.supplier ='" & supplierId & "'
```

Clearly `tableName` and `supplierId` are variables passed in from the call to this function and determine which supplier's prices we are dealing with, and therefore, which products in the database to be looking at.

This works fine, it matches the `sku` field in the products table, to the `sku` field in the suppliers price list and updates price related fields accordingly, and also UPCs if available.

There are two cases that are not handled:

- If a product is discontinued, no `sku` match will be found as item is removed from pricelist, but may remain in `products` table
- If a `sku` has been incorrectly entered into the `products` table, the match will fail.

So, what I want to do is get a list of items who's `supplierId` field in `products` matches that of the supplier price list being updated, but do not appear in the pricelist.

I can do this by looping records of course, but how would I do it with 1 sql statement, or even better, incorporate it in the above?

Comment: As an aside : Having the same data structure for multiple tables is a SQL Anti-Pattern.  Instead of `PriceList_gibson` and `PriceList_whatever`, just have `PriceList` and add an extra field to it.  Then you won't need to dynamically form the SQL;  `'gibson'` can just be a parameter.  This will also mean that you can get execution plan recaching.  And more reliable testing, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Yeh, I might change to that in future, it would make more sense long term, currently it'd make the uploading of data to the tables complicated. I take your point though! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** To get rows that exist in `product` but do not exist in `" & tableName & "`...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  product                 pp
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  " & tableName & "       p
    ON p.sku= pp.sku
WHERE
  pp.supplier = '" & supplierId & "'
  AND p.sku IS NULL
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  product
WHERE
  supplier = '" & supplierId & "'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM " & tableName & " WHERE sku = product.sku)
```

Comment: Nearly, I need items which exist in `products` but not `PriceList_gibson` tried amending your query to do it, but I'm not getting it right! I'm using mySQL too, so the OUTER JOIN doesn't work!

Comment: @JamieHartnoll - Answer amended based on your comment.